# Have I just deleted my kernel?

Tags: apt, kernel, virtualbox, dpkg

I'm working on a VirtualBox hosted headless Ubuntu which looks like this :

```
foo@bar:~> uname -r
3.13.0-100-generic
foo@bar:~> lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS
Release:        14.04
Codename:       trusty
```

I just tried to delete some old kernel headers by executing :

```
sudo apt-get remove linux-image-3.13.0-4* linux-headers-3.13.0-4*
```

Which I thought would remove a very restricted set of old kernel headers. The text that appeared on the sceen however included :

```
Removing linux-generic (3.13.0.100.108) ...
Removing linux-headers-generic (3.13.0.100.108) ...
Removing linux-headers-3.13.0-100-generic (3.13.0-100.147) ...
Removing linux-headers-3.13.0-100 (3.13.0-100.147) ...
Removing linux-image-generic (3.13.0.100.108) ...
Removing linux-image-extra-3.13.0-100-generic (3.13.0-100.147) ...
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal 3.13.0-100-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-100-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools 3.13.0-100-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-100-generic
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-100-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/update-notifier 3.13.0-100-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-100-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub 3.13.0-100-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-100-generic
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-100-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-100-generic
Found memtest86+ image: /memtest86+.elf
Found memtest86+ image: /memtest86+.bin
done
Removing linux-image-3.13.0-100-generic (3.13.0-100.147) ...
WARN: Proceeding with removing running kernel image.
```

Which indicates that in fact I have trashed the current kernel headers !

Having said that when I run

`dpkg -l linux-image-* linux-headers-*`

I can still see :

```
rc  linux-image-3.13.0-100-generic              3.13.0-100.147             amd64                      Linux kernel image for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SM
```

and

```
rc  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-100-generic        3.13.0-100.147             amd64                      Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
```

Which is pretty strange !

So my questions are :

**First** have I deleted the Kernel headers if dpkg still shows them ?

**Second** most of the solutions to this problem involve using a live CD to manipulate the file system. I can't see how I can do this when I'm dealing with a Virtualbox hosted VM - how can I take that approach (or is there a better one ?).

---

**EDIT**: Based on the comments by user.dz and 'Organic Marble' I'm trying to use the original install ISO to boot as a LiveCD. This seems to start OK but the second screen presented to me looks like this :

[image]

And none of those seem relevant to booting as a LiveCD. What I don't want to do (for obvious reasons) is to overwrite the existing machine configuration.

Just to be clear I should say that from within "VirtualBox Manager" I've changed the settings on the problem VM so that it boots from the ISO I downloaded in order to create the VM originally.

I'd appreciate some advice :

- Am I on the right track ?
- If so which of the options presented are relevant to my situation ?

---

**EDIT 2**

Based on more comments I have now started a Ubuntu 14 VM based on a desktop ISO. Before starting it I added the VM I have problems with as a hard disk, like this :

[image: Storage Configuration of Desktop VM being used to try to fix the original problem VM]

The disk with the green bubble around it is the disk belonging to the VM which I can no longer boot because I deleted the kernel.

Having done that I started the VM and looked around for the files belonging to the 'problem VM'. I found it in a directory at `/media/ubuntu/f17f8ab5-065f-4e05-835e-8cd0380b9e2b` so following the directions here https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1034523&p=6518991#post6518991 I tried :

```
sudo mount /media/ubuntu/f17f8ab5-065f-4e05-835e-8cd0380b9e2b /mnt
```

but I get an error message :

```
mount: /media/ubuntu/f17f8ab5-065f-4e05-835e-8cd0380b9e2b is not a block device
```

So how can I do this if the directory is not a block device (which it's clearly not).

Comment: (1) You've removed the kernel and its header too, `rc` is a code 1st letter is `Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold` & 2nd letter is `Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend` so it means *package Removed & Conf-files still in system*, check `man dpkg` for details. (2) how about adding that virtual hdd image to another virtual machine as a  secondary drive.

Comment: You can boot your virtualbox to a live CD image - this is probably how you installed it in the first place.  Under settings/storage just click the optical drive and point it to an ubuntu .iso file on your host's hard drive.

Comment: To run a useful live session, download a desktop .iso, not the server version. The 'rescue' option on the server .iso might give you a command line, but I am not familiar with the server .iso.

Comment: @user.dz - Thanks for your help so far. If you were able to comment on the 'EDIT 2' I have added I would appreciate it.

Comment: @OrganicMarble - Thanks for your help so far. If you were able to comment on the 'EDIT 2' I have added I would appreciate it.

Comment: I'm not sure why you made all these changes. I would just boot the original VM you are having problems with, using the live CD.

Comment: @glaucon, use `sudo fdisk -l` to get the list of disks and its partitions, then use `/dev/sdXY` in the mount command.

Comment: @glaucon, do you still facing this issue. could you add `sudo fdisk -l`  the question?